# Unable to install Go dep

Tags: 16.04, dependencies, gnome-terminal, golang

I am trying to run the command `dep ensure` on my Ubuntu 16.04, but the system is unable to find the command. When I run `sudo apt install dep` or any other installation commands, I always get this error when I run `dep ensure`:

```
No command 'dep' found, did you mean:
 Command 'dp' from package 'speech-tools' (universe)
 Command 'iep' from package 'emboss' (universe)
 Command 'dwp' from package 'binutils' (main)
 Command 'dex' from package 'dex' (universe)
 Command 'rep' from package 'rep' (universe)
 Command 'delp' from package 'fp-utils-3.0.0' (universe)
 Command 'xep' from package 'pvm-examples' (universe)
dep: command not found
```

Someone tells me I need Ubuntu 18 to run `dep`, but I would like to know how I can install this on my current Ubuntu. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see if a package is available in the repo's you use, type `apt-cache search dep` or `apt-cache search go-dep`.

Go dep is not available in the 16.04 repo's. It is available in the [18.04 repo's](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/go-dep), so 'someone' was (at least partially) right.

Maybe you can install it from [Github](https://github.com/golang/dep)?

Comment: No luck with Github. Thanks for the response, I know now what the issue is!

Comment: @Ruby Can you post your own answer to share the solution ?

Comment: Seriously @ruby

Answer (score 2):

**Install and usage of go-dep on Ubuntu 16.04:**

Create `bin` directory inside `$GOPATH`

```
cd $GOPATH
mkdir bin
```

Now download the compiled `dep` file.

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/golang/dep/master/install.sh | sh
```

Copy the `dep` file from `$GOPATH/go/bin` to the project's root location.

Execute the `dep` file with commands

```
./dep [command]
```

`dep` commands:

```
Usage: "dep [command]"

Commands:

  init     Set up a new Go project, or migrate an existing one
  status   Report the status of the project's dependencies
  ensure   Ensure a dependency is safely vendored in the project
  version  Show the dep version information
  check    Check if imports, Gopkg.toml, and Gopkg.lock are in sync

Examples:
  dep init                               set up a new project
  dep ensure                             install the project's dependencies
  dep ensure -update                     update the locked versions of all dependencies
  dep ensure -add github.com/pkg/errors  add a dependency to the project

Use "dep help [command]" for more information about a command.
```

Comment: wouldn't be better to add `$GOPATH/go/bin` to `PATH` instead of copying it to project root location?

Answer (score 2):

You can have it in your PATH

```
curl -LO https://raw.githubusercontent.com/golang/dep/master/install.sh
chmod 700 install.sh
./install.sh
chmod +x $GOPATH/bin/dep
sudo mv $GOPATH/bin/dep /usr/local/bin/
```

so you can call it from everywhere `dep`

Comment: Prefer "chmod +x" rather than using octal numbers.  It's clearer.  In this case, it doesn't matter if others and group can execute the script.